# How to add more restrictions in authentication using CakePHP?

Tags: cakephp

I'm using the Acl and Auth components in CakePHP, actually the application are validating the Username and Password of the user, but now I need to validate if the user is active. Actually I use the

```
$this->Auth->autoRedirect = false;
```

to do some stuff after the authentication. There's a way to do this without making another query to the database in the login action? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$this->Auth->userScope = array('User.active'=>1);
```